# Where can I find an online elevation profile of the Cohos trail?

Tags: backpacking, thru-hike, new-england

Where can I find an elevation profile of the [Cohos trail](http://www.cohostrail.org/)?

Comment: Charlie's answer seems a good start. Failing that, you could check running/hiking apps like Strava. I found **[this](https://www.strava.com/segments/8088116)** quite quickly, don't know if it's really what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion would be to create a path in Google Earth and then view the elevation profile of the path.

Here is an example of what that would look like,

[image: Screenshot of Google Earth]

One caveat, Google Earth underestimates the steepness because instead of [calculating slope as rise/run it uses rise/hypotenuse](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/14758/8794).