# What are the slope determination criteria in the elevation profile of Google Earth? Is it based on rise over run or rise over hypotenuse?

Tags: navigation

I occasionally use google earth and notice that the slope percentage is never cross 100%, if slope percentage is determined by rise over run method the 100 percent value is equal to a 45-degree slope angle. By noticing this a doubt is arise on my preconceived notion and I begin some online research but could not find anything about the slope determination criteria in the elevation profile of Google Earth. I also search on Google Earth's official website for any reference source but could not find anything. Is Google Earth's slope determination criteria in the elevation profile is based on rise over the hypotenuse? Please provide a reference source from Google Earth where they mentioned about the slope determination criteria in the elevation profile it will be very helpfull.

Comment: Rise over run is normal; I suspect it's just bad at handling cliffs and other very steep stuff. It expects roads/tracks/paths which rarely go over 45 degrees. Of course steeper paths exist, but they're not common, and the run is almost always very short. The short run will mean it disappears in averaging - elevation data isn't continuous and isn't even necessarily on a fine grid

Comment: Slopes of 100% or above are extremely rare on Earth -- about the only place you find them is cliffs, and I don't think Google Earth's elevation data is good enough to show cliffs.

Comment: The https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/14757/how-do-you-correct-google-earths-incorrect-slope-percentage answers say it is rise over hypotenuse.